# calling method of class in jsp using jsp tags

Tags: java, jsp

```
Class Foo
{
   public String currentVersion()
   {
     return "1.2";
   }
}
```

need to call **currentVersion** class method from jsp using tag library? where currentversion is not getter or setter method ,it is just a class method.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with standard JSP expressions like `${foo.currentVersion}`, that only works with bean proprties (i.e. `getCurrentVersion()`).

You need to either

- Write a scriptlet (don't do it!)
- Write a custom tag class that calls `currentVersion()` for you
- Refactor `Foo` to have a `getCurrentVersion()` method

Comment: how shall i write custom tag in order to call that method ?

Comment: Blah, I had a feeling that was the answer when I saw this.  I *really* didn't want to have to write my own custom tag class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply rename you method to `getCurrentVersion()`, [**there is nothing in the JavaBeans specification that says that a "getter" method has to return the value of an attribute on the class**](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javabeans/docs/spec.html). A getter method can simply return a constant value like you have.

```
class Foo {
    public String getCurrentVersion() {
        return "1.2";
   }
}
```